# Where to specify port number for SignalR package

Tags: angular, signalr

I am pretty new to the Microsoft `SignalR` package software.

My question is: how can one specify the port number to wait on the `SignalR` hub server side (Visual Studio 2022 c#).
I see a lot of examples with the specified port number on the client side (e.g. `connection = new HubConnectionBuilder().withUrl(('https://localhost:7219/<your endpoint>'));`),
but can't see similar way of specifying port number on which communication happens on the server side.

Comment: I think this is a good explanation by Martin Liversage https://stackoverflow.com/a/37333219/12252417